# Select lists from a list of lists based on values in a vector

Tags: r, list, lapply

A very simple question. I have a list of 10813 lists and a vector of 3415 IDs. Each of the 10813 lists has a name that corresponds to one of the IDs in the vector. I want to extract the lists corresponding to the IDs in the vector.

Something like this:

```
mylist <- list("1"=list(),"2"=list(),"3"=list(),"4"=list(),"5"=list(),"6"=list())
myIDs <- c(2:4)
```

So, I'd like my new list to include just lists 2, 3, and 4:

```
myNEWlist
$`2`
list()

$`3`
list()

$`4`
list()
```

With a data frame is straightforward (e.g., `%in% myIDs`), but I cannot find an easy solution for list of lists. I tried unsuccessfully `mylist[myIDs]` and with lapply, sapply, purrr.

I hope this is not too silly.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that indexing a list by integer (as you're doing with `2:4`) can easily be different than indexing by name. It should not be assumed that `mylist[[1]]` is the same as `mylist[["1"]]`, at least not from a defensive-programming viewpoint. Since you named the second object `myIDs`, I'm inferring the names themselves, in which case you want `mylist[as.character(myIDs)]` here.

Comment: Hi @r2evans! Thanks a lot, I was missing `as.character`.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Fran in the comments you are missing as.character to be able to match the indices.

```
mylist <- list("1"=list(),"2"=list(),"3"=list(),"4"=list(),"5"=list(),"6"=list())

myIDs <- as.character(c(2:4))

>mylist[myIDs]

$`2`
list()

$`3`
list()

$`4`
list()
```